# Can I use a sql query or script to create format description files for multiple tables in an IBM DB2 for System I database?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have an AS400 with an IBM DB2 database and I need to create a Format Description File (FDF) for each table in the DB. I can create the FDF file using the IBM Export tool but it will only create one file at a time which will take several days to complete. I have not found a way to create the files systematically using a tool or query. Is this possible or should this be done using scripting?

Comment: Scripting, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to correct a misunderstanding...

A Format Description File has nothing at all to do with the format of a Db2 table.  It actually describes the format of the data in a stream file that you are uploading into the Db2 table.  Sure you can turn on an option during the download from Db2 to create the FDF file, but it's still actually describing the data in the stream file you've just downloaded the data into.  You can use the resulting FDF file to upload a modified version of the downloaded data or as the starting point for creating an FDF file that matches the actual data you want to upload.

Which explain why there's no built-in way to create an appropriate FDF file for every table on the system.

I question why you think you actually to generate an FDF file for every table.

As I recall, the format of the FDF (or it's newer variant FDFX) is pretty simple; it shouldn't be all that difficult to generate if you really wanted to. But I don't have one handy at the moment, and my Google-FU has failed me.

Comment: I have a client that requested the FDF for all tables that we are exporting out of the database in order to perform a data migration from one system to another. Thier migration tool requires the raw data (csv) and an associated FDF file for validation purposes. My question was specific to systematically creating these files by either a query or script. Maybe there is a tool someone knows about that can do this relatively quick rather than the IBM export tool which creates it one file at a time.  I am not well versed in DB2 scripting which is where I think is the answer.